# Multiple Embedded HSQLDB databases in jUnit errors during build

Tags: spring, spring-batch, junit4, hsqldb, spring-test

I'm working on a new Spring Batch (3.0.3.RELEASE) application where there will be multiple databases accessed during the jobs.  For testing we are using HSQLDB (2.3.2) as the embedded database.

In my Application context I have the following.

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="proDataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:script-tables.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:script-constraints.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="altDataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:script-alt-tables.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

When I run a single test in Eclipse, things are fine.  When I build from the command line, after the first test, I get errors

```
Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 3 of resource class path resource [script-promrkt-promo.sql]
object name already exists: PROMRKT
```

It appears to me that the population process in EmbeddedDatabaseFactory is receiving an already populated database.  From what I can tell is that after each test there is not a SHUTDOWN being executed and HSQLDB is leaving the already populated database in memory.

I have re-reviewed the documentation and in a [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-embedded-database-dao-testing) this does show a explicit shutdown command.  But if spring starts up the embedded database when my test starts why doesn't it shut it down when the test completes ?

1. Is it expected the embedded databases will remain after each unit test for the same application context?
2. What is the order that spring starts up an embedded database and when is the transactional context initialized?
3. Do I need to use a database cleaner ?
4. Can the populate be updated to only populate when the database is first started, and rollback to the original script configuration when my test is complete ( kinda like how the AbstractTransactionalSpringContextTests worked )
5. Do I need some transactional markers?  Spring Batch's JobRepo is properly being populated and destroyed between each test.  Why are my custom dataSources not ?

Comment: Just to confirm, you are not using any type of connection pool during test?  I ask because of this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11372

Comment: No, connection pools.  At least I have not explicitly said to pool.  I read the issue and that could be related.  Doesn't bode well where one of the comments recommends no more that one embedded DB at a time.  Any ideas of where I can implement a spring interface to fix/improve this behavior ?

Answer (score 3):

The script the log message is complaining about isn't in your configuration.  I presume it's being executed somewhere else?  If that's the case, you'll probably need to add `@DirtiesContext` to your tests so that Spring doesn't cache the context (I'm assuming you're using the `SpringJunit4Runner` with `@ContextConfiguration` but can't be sure since your actual test isn't in the question).

If my assumption is correct, Spring caches the context in an effort to improve performance over the running of a unit test suite.  If your test modifies the context in a way that can impact other tests (like running scripts in one test that need to be run again in others), you mark the tests with `@DirtiesContext` and Spring won't cache the context.  You can use the annotation at either the method or class level.  You can read more about the annotation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time looking at this and reading the Spring Framework documentation (gasp!) and tracing through code.  There are some interesting changes in 4.1 spring core, especially the testing.

I found out that ApplicationContext(s) are cached at the JVM level now.  If a second test asks for a context the TestContext looks first in it's cache to see if some other test has already asked for the identical configuration.

I have some profiles for some of my tests.  A test with a different profile but the same @ContextConfiguration causes the that context to be re-loaded with the profile applied.  When the "Bean Loader" arrives at creating the embedded databases, the EmbeddedDatabaseFactory does not take into consideration that the embedded database (in memory HSQLDB) may have already been created or cached from previous tests and does not need to be re-initialized.

Therefore I added some logic to the EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.initDatabase() checking if the database already exists before re-initializing & running the DatabasePopulator.

```
    List existingDataBases = org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabaseURIs();

    boolean isExisting = false;
    String localDBName = StringUtils.lowerCase(this.databaseName);

    for (Object object : existingDataBases) {
        if (object.toString().contains(localDBName)) {
            isExisting = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Now populate the database
    if (!isExisting && this.databasePopulator != null) {
```

( of course this isn't quite kosher for what spring would need but it gets the point across )

In my opinion it looks like an issue partially with the EmbeddedDatabaseFactory and the TestContext caching mechanism.  My "jdbc:embedded-database" definitions do not have any profiles associated with them.  Why does the cache need to re-create them and not load them out of the existing cached beans?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force creation of new embedded database by setting unique name with `generateUniqueName(true)` each time new object is created.

Here is an example:

```
embeddedDatabase = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .generateUniqueName(true)
            .addScripts("db/sql/create-db.sql", "db/sql/insert-data.sql")
            .build();
```